# Add class to parent element on click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have following code:

```
<li class="parentElement">
 <ul>
   <li class="highlight"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

`<ul>` in here is a dropdown in navigation menu. Active element/`<li>` have class highlight...
I need to add class active to parentElement when class highlight is in one of the list element.

I was trying to use ng-class but without success.

UPDATE

ng-class="{'active': hasHighlight}" will not work with my code, it will add activ permanently as highlight is present all time in ng-class:

```
            <li class="parentElement">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li ng-class="{ highlight: isActive('/item1')}"><a href="${createLink(uri: '/#/item1')}"></a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ highlight: isActive('/item2')}"><a href="${createLink(uri: '/#/item2')}"></a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{ highlight: isActive('/item3')}"><a href="${createLink(uri: '/#/item3')}"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

Comment: Is the 'highlight' class added dynamically through any function of some sort?

Comment: Using jQuery at all, or is pure Angular?

Comment: it's added by controller

Comment: Angular comes with jqLite -- I would make a directive and attach it to the `UL` -- basically saying that if a child `li` has class `highlight`, add a class to the parent `li`

Answer (score 1):

You were right about using `ng-class`.

```
<li class="parentElement" ng-class="{'active': hasHighlight}">
 <ul>
   <li class="highlight"><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
 </ul>
</li>
```

In your controller, whenever you add the class `highlight` to the list element, change `$scope.hasHighlight` to equal `true`. When it's taken off, change it to `false`.

Comment: Yep, just what I thought

Comment: Can you also provide your code for your controller?

Answer (score 0):

I have found something like this:

```
ng-class="{ active: isAnyActive() }"
```

and controller:

```
$scope.isAnyActive = function() {
        return ['/item1','/item2','item3'].indexOf($location.path()) > -1;
    };
```