# Angular UI Bootstrap Accordion Adding a Class to header

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accordion

I have the following accordion which is working fine

```
<accordion-group is-open="open.first">
        <accordion-heading>
          My Title
        </accordion-heading>
</accordion-group>
```

The "Accordion-heading" directive translates into something like

```
    <h4 class="panel-title">
    <a class="accordion-toggle" 
accordion-transclude="heading" ng-click="toggleOpen()" href="">
My Title
    </h4>
```

What I want is when someone clicks on this accordion option/title is to add to toggle a class on the h4 attribute. In jquery I would do it like this

```
$('.panel-heading .panel-title').on('click', function () {   
    $(this).toggleClass('actives'); 
 });
```

I think I have to do it as a directive, but not quite sure how ?

Comment: Using the developertools "f12" i see that the panel has an "in" class added when it is open.

Comment: From there you can do something like: 
$(this).addClass('someClass');
$(mySelector).trigger('cssClassChanged')
$(otherSelector).bind('cssClassChanged', data, function(){ do stuff });

Comment: thats the content panel, the heading panel gets nothing added when toggled

Comment: When I try adding it is as pure jquery it doesnt seem to trigger I think due to page loads and view loading different times etc I think it needs to be added via a directive

Comment: modified copy from https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations

    myModule.directive('my-directive', ['$animate', function($animate) {
      return function(scope, element, attrs) {        
        element.on('click', function() {
          // find all elements with 'in' class inside
        });
      };
    }]);

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21764606/angularjs-add-class-to-parent-element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using `ng-repeat` on your `<accordion-group>` directive, you can do something like this:

```
<accordion-group ng-repeat="group in groups" ng-init="group.isOpen = false" ng-class="{'open': group.isOpen}" is-open="group.isOpen">
```

This initializes a new `$scope` variable in `ng-init` called `isOpen` that is attached to the individual group you are repeating over (`group.isOpen`). In my example above, I've made it false so that all accordion groups are closed on load, and then assigning that variable to `is-open`. When you click or "open" one of the accordion groups, the directive will automatically change `group.isOpen` to `true`. This will then allow the `ng-class` expression to evaluate `true` as well and add the class "open" to the panel-heading in the DOM.